# SQL - WHERE AND OR with Sub Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a 'where' query in which I am specifying a list of 'likes' as well as a sub 'where' query.  This query is returning as though it is ignoring the sub query.

I have tried CONTAINS and WHERE IN but no luck.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[listofmachines]
Where LastDateTime <= GETDATE() - 28
and ComputerName like 'PC%' 
OR ComputerName like 'LP%'
OR ComputerName like 'LAPTOP%'
AND LatestVersion < (
 SELECT MAX(LatestVersion) as 'Current Version'
 from [SomeOther].[Table]
 )
```

The results contain record where the 'LatestVersion' column shows a range of values rather than one.

Comment: You need parentheses.  I'm voting to close as a typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to put your OR condition in bracket-

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[listofmachines]
Where LastDateTime <= GETDATE() - 28
and 
( 
  ComputerName like 'PC%' OR ComputerName like 'LP%' OR ComputerName like 'LAPTOP%'
)
AND LatestVersion < 
 (
   SELECT MAX(LatestVersion) from [SomeOther].[Table]
 )
```